# Hammer.js event in a Cordova app firing only on second attempt

Tags: javascript, cordova, hammer.js

In my `Cordova` app, I refresh the screen like so:

```
$('.main-panel').empty();
//using underscore template
$('.main-panel').html(_.template($("#tpl-alertpanel").html(),{alerts : alerts}));

//wire hammer.js event
Hammer($('#alertpanel')).on("swipedown dragdown", function() {
   console.log('>>>>>>>>>>>>' + $(this).attr('id') + $(this).scrollTop());
});
```

**Problem:**

After the above refresh the `swipedown` event fires only at the second attempt - meaning that I have to `swipedown` once with no effect and then again to make the event fire.  Or I could just tap first and then swipe to make the swipe event fire.

I am thinking that this may have something to do with the fact that I am emptying the `DOM` elements under `$('.main-panel')` and replacing it dynamically.

I tried to programmatically trigger the `first tap` like so, with no effect:

```
$('.main-panel').click(); 
$('.main-panel').focus();
```

I am testing this on **Android 4.4.2**

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: just curious, why call empty() if just after you replace the content wjth html()?

Comment: @QuickFix - to empty old data and then show new data

Comment: yes but html replaces the old data if any, so doesn't empty add not very usefull dom operation.

Comment: @QuickFix - Your are right - jquery doc says - `When .html() is used to set an element's content, any content that was in that element is completely replaced by the new content. Additionally, jQuery removes other constructs such as data and event handlers from child elements before replacing those elements with the new content.`  I did try without `$('.main-panel').empty()` - that has not improved the situation

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered a work-around - not sure if this is the right solution.

If I refresh my main-panel within a `setTimeout`, the Hammer events are firing at first attempt.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    refreshMainPanel();
}, 100);
```